# Iterate through all the children of a tree item

Tags: qt, qt5

Currently i am iterating through all the child items of a Tree item using this code.

```
void  iterate(const QModelIndex & index, const QAbstractItemModel * model)
 {
if (index.isValid())
{
    // Do action here
}

if (!model->hasChildren(index) || (index.flags() & 
Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren))
{
    return;
}
auto rows = model->rowCount(index);
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    iterate(model->index(i, 0, index), model);
  }
```

i need to Iterate using TreeItem instead of index

```
 void  iterate(TreeItem *item, const QAbstractItemModel * model)
```

One method i can think of is getting the index of the item using createIndex function and the above code will work with it.

Is there any other method to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `QStandardItemModel` you can use the `indexFromItem` methods:

QModelIndex QStandardItemModel::indexFromItem(const QStandardItem *item) const

In case you are using your own implementation of you might provide your own `indexFromItem` and `itemFromIndex` methods.

Another solution might involve calling `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex`.

Comment: i am using AbstractItemModel .

Comment: All right, but what is the concrete instance of `QAbstractItemModel`. You need to subclass it inorder to do something.